# Delete a array element from a Firestore database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete an element from an array in a Firestore document. However, none of the approaches I tried had worked so far. My last attempt was like this:

```
  const ref = firestore().collection('events').doc(extraid);
  ref.get().then(document => {
    const thing = document.data();
    const rejected = thing.rejected || [];
    const interested = thing.interested || [];

    const fieldIndex = interested.findIndex(obj => obj.interestedId === sender);
    const fieldToDelete = interested[fieldIndex];
    firebase.firestore.FieldValue(fieldToDelete);
    firebase.firestore.FieldValue.delete(fieldToDelete);
  });
```

How can I delete an element from an array in a Firestore document?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to [update()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array) the modified array field back to the document as suggested by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data).  Calling `FieldValue.delete()` isn't enough - that just creates a FieldValue token that you can pass to `update()` to make the change.  It will look something like this:

```
ref.update('interested', FieldValue.delete(fieldToDelete))
```